# Using URFetchApp with Google Forms API returns 400 ccode error

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms, urlfetch

I'm trying  to use the new Google Forms API to add an image to an existing Google form. At the moment I'm just trying to change the image Alt Text. I haven't been able to get it to work. I keep getting a 400 error. I'm hooping someone can point out what I'm doing wrong.

TIA for any help

This is the code:

```
function callFormsAPI() {
  Logger.log('Calling the Forms API!');
  var formId =  "1oxBZrRG6UEcrLSXrT9P9hcqgkvE12UQDYUOAYyg3eeA"
   
  // Get OAuth Token
  var OAuthToken = ScriptApp.getOAuthToken();
  Logger.log('OAuth token is: ' + OAuthToken);
  
  var path = "https://forms.googleapis.com/v1beta/forms/"
  
  var formsAPIUrl = path+formId+':batchUpdate'  

  Logger.log('formsAPIUrl is: ' + formsAPIUrl);
  
  var body = tempAPI()
  var options = {
    'headers': {
      Authorization: 'Bearer ' + OAuthToken,
      Accept: 'application/json'
    },
    muteHttpExceptions: true,
    'method': 'post',
    'payload' : JSON.stringify(body)
    //     'payload' : body
    
  };  
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(formsAPIUrl, options);
  Logger.log('Response from forms.responses was: ' + response);
  var text = response.getContentText()
  console.log(text)
}


function tempAPI(){
  var itemId = "2005660890"
  var imageString = 'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1552519507-da3b142c6e3d';
  
  var request = {
    "requests": [
      {
        "updateItem": {
          "item": {
            "itemId": itemId,           
            
            "questionItem": {
              "image": {
                "altText": 'this is a car',
//                "sourceUri": imageString
              }
            }
          },
           "updateMask": "altText"
//         "updateMask": "item/questionItem/image/sourceUri"

        } //end of update item
      }
    ]
  }
return request
}
```

This is the response I'm getting

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name \"{\"requests\":[{\"updateItem\":{\"item\":{\"itemId\":\"2005660890\",\"questionItem\":{\"image\":{\"altText\":\"this is a car\"}}},\"updateMask\":\"altText\"}}]}\": Cannot bind query parameter. Field '{\"requests\":[{\"updateItem\":{\"item\":{\"itemId\":\"2005660890\",\"questionItem\":{\"image\":{\"altText\":\"this is a car\"}}},\"updateMask\":\"altText\"}}]}' could not be found in request message.",
    "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT",
    "details": [
      {
        "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.BadRequest",
        "fieldViolations": [
          {
            "description": "Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name \"{\"requests\":[{\"updateItem\":{\"item\":{\"itemId\":\"2005660890\",\"questionItem\":{\"image\":{\"altText\":\"this is a car\"}}},\"updateMask\":\"altText\"}}]}\": Cannot bind query parameter. Field '{\"requests\":[{\"updateItem\":{\"item\":{\"itemId\":\"2005660890\",\"questionItem\":{\"image\":{\"altText\":\"this is a car\"}}},\"updateMask\":\"altText\"}}]}' could not be found in request message."
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: I tried to repro using your code, but stuck at enabling Forms API: 'Google Forms API has not been used in project 123456789 before or it is disabled.' Also it provides link to enable it: 'Enable it by visiting https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/forms.googleapis.com/overview?project=123456789 then retry.' but it doesn't open: Failed to load. Hopefully someone more lucky than me will help you.

Comment: I think that in your script, in order to remove your issue, it is required to add `contentType: "application/json"` to `options` and in order to modify `altText`, `updateMask` is required to be `questionItem/image/altText` or `questionItem.image.altText`. By this, your current error could be removed.

Comment: But, unfortunately, in the current stage, it seems that `altText` and `sourceUri` cannot be modified using the batchUpdate method. I thought that this might be a bug. But, Google Forms API is growing now. So I believe that this issue will be resolved in the future update. And, this issue was reported to the Google issue tracker. https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/216910916

Comment: Thank you. Moving the contentType from the headers to options stopped it throwing errors. But you are right I am able to make changes to things like the question and the description but not to the image. Fingers crossed Google will get that fixed soon